# BlueSmirf and Adruino - TX seems not to be working

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, processing

I'm testing transmission of data via bluetooth. The data are recognized by my Arduino module. But I don't get any signal come out from my bluetooth module. I have no idea how to test that. (The TX and RX LED from my Arduino are not blinking too when I connect the blueTooth module. I don't know if it is normal. They are blinking normally when I don't connect anything into the UART).

I'm working in the Monsky Wifi project if that can help you. (from Make things talk book).

What is strange is that when I'm testing my Ardiuno from USB, the dialogue is working great between my processing program and my Arduino. My processing program send a signal, my Arduino module respond to it. And when my processing program has all the data it needs, it asks for more to the Arduino and the cycle continue.

Now, when I do the same with the bluetooth serial connection, the connection is well done (my blueSmirf green LED is up), data are sent (when my Arduino receive a signal, a LED blinks for this purpose). But my processing program doesn't receive any data signal. 
I have already checked the baud rate (9600 for the bluetooth). And I'm connecting to the `/dev/tty.myBluetooth`. So I don't know what is wrong.

Do you have an idea of what could make this happen?

*** Edit ***

Ok I figured out. To those who will get into this kind of trouble, it was really the baudRate who was misconfigured into my bluetooth module. That explain why the transmission of data worked, not the reception.

The fact is I was changing the bluetooth Bps rate but not permanently, so when I was reading the bluetooth configuration it was actually diplaying the not permanently BaudRate. So typping the

> SU, 96

in my bluetooth command mode resolved my issued. (My arduino was configured to send at 9600 too, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured out. To those who will get into this kind of trouble, it was really the baudRate who was misconfigured into my bluetooth module. That explain why the transmission of data worked, not the reception.

The fact is I was changing the bluetooth Bps rate but not permanently, so when I was reading the bluetooth configuration it was actually diplaying the not permanently BaudRate. So typping the

SU, 96
in my bluetooth command mode resolved my issued. (My arduino was configured to send at 9600 too, of course).